# Firebase realtime database transaction and cloud functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a list in the Firebase realtime database, structured as follows:

```
list: {
  change: {
    rate: integer,
    last: Date
  },
  lock: string,
  elements: {
    ...
  },
  size: integer
}
```

Clients only add elements to the list.
There is a cloud function triggered by `onCreate` event on elements' child. It transactionaly increments `list.size` in the database and then performs calculations on elements possibly involving removing all or some children.
And there is another cloud function triggered by `onDelete` event on elements' children which only transactionaly decrements `list.size` in the database.
The issue is that the counter becomes inaccurate after some time. Sometimes it shows more elements that there are in the list, sometimes less.
Below is the [adapted] code:

```js
exports.element_add = functions.database.ref('/list/elements/{element}).onCreate(
  (snapshot, context) => {
    const elements = snapshot.ref.parent;

    return new Promise(
      (resolve, reject) => {
        const start = new Date().getTime();

        async.waterfall(
          [
            // read and write to list.change
            // ...
            (next) => {
              // increment list size
              _changeSize(elements.parent, +1, 1, next)
            },
            // acquire lock if required and do calculations on list elements
            // ...
          ],
          // finally
          function (e) {
            // release the lock
            // ...
            // handle errors
            if (e)
              return reject(e);

            resolve();
          }
        );
      });
  });


exports.element_remove = functions.database.ref('/list/elements/{element}).onDelete(
  (snapshot, context) => {
    const elements = snapshot.ref.parent;

    return new Promise(
      function (resolve, reject) {
        _changeSize(elements.parent, -1, 1,
          function (e) {
            if (e)
              return reject(e);

            resolve();
          }
        )
      }
    )
  });

function _changeSize(list, delta, attempt, done) {
  list.child('size').transaction(
    // update
    (size) => {
      if (size === null)
        return null;

      return size + delta;
    },
    // finally
    (e, committed, snapshot) {
      if (e) {
        console.error(`size transaction error: ${e}, retrying in 1 sec`);

        // try again
        return setTimeout(_changeSize, 1000, list, delta, attempt + 1, done);
      }

      console.log(committed ? `new list size is ${snapshot.val()}` : 'list size was not updated');

      // return new size if committed
      done(null, committed ? snapshot.val() : undefined);
    },
    // do not apply locally
    false
  );
}
```

Except for the two cloud functions above no other entity is working with `list.size`. The question is why is the value of `list.size` gets out of sync with `list.elements`?

**Update 2020-02-26**: Apparently some of onCreate/onDelete events is being received more than once! We've observed them arriving even 3 times spread between instances of the cloud function. Is it a normal behavior or something we're doing wrong?

Comment: You mention a Realtime Database **transaction**. How do you execute the transaction? Why don't you use the standard transaction mechanism (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions)?

Comment: Transaction is actually used in `_changeSize()`. Please look at the first line there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a Realtime Database [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#transaction).

As follows for incrementing:

```
exports.element_add = functions.database.ref('/list/elements/{element}').onCreate(
  (snapshot, context) => {

    const sizeRef = admin
    .database()
    .ref('/list/size');

    return sizeRef
      .transaction(current_value => {
        return (current_value || 0) + 1;
      });

});
```

and as follows for decrementing:

```
exports.element_delete = functions.database.ref('/list/elements/{element}').onDelete(
  (snapshot, context) => {

    const sizeRef = admin
    .database()
    .ref('/list/size');

    return sizeRef
      .transaction(current_value => {
        if (current_value > 0) {
            return current_value - 1;
        } else  {
           //Normally we should never reach this line...
           return null;
        }
      });

});
```

Comment: Transaction is actually used in `_changeSize()`. Please look at the first line there.

Comment: Are you using a genuine Realtime Database transaction or you are using another `node.js` library to implement this "transaction"?

Comment: The genuine one. The `_changeSize` receives "list" ref, then it starts a transaction on `list.size`.

Comment: Can you add to your question the exact code of `_changeSize`?

Comment: It's all there, in the code snippet. There are 3 function in the snippet. `_changeSize()` is the last one.

Comment: [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#transaction) returns a Promise and you don't return this promise. This is absolutely key in Cloud Functions, in order to correctly manage the lifecycle of your Cloud Function, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions. Having said that, if I may, I don't understand why you have such a complicated code, using some locks, etc. You should give a try to the code in my answer, normally it will totally fulfill your needs.

Comment: I do return a promise from cloud functions, `_changeSize()` returns when transaction is finished, it returns the new list size as it is only a part of processing code which then reads the elements and processes them. I will probably extract the size increment code to a separate cloud function, though it will increase the costs as there will be more invocations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206917/discussion-between-renaud-tarnec-and-faraway).